# Extract significant parts of an AWS authorization header string

Tags: php, preg-match-all, text-extraction, authorization-header

My input string:

```
AWS-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIngtc3MiOjEy/20160911/cn/user-service/request,SignedHeaders=host;x-aws-date, Signature=d9ee2d43f2067e4b8857f15fa8fff27820051d95a4ec31e93be866f201e0797a
```

How can I get the values for `Credential`, `SignedHeaders`, and `Signature`?

Comment: You need to provide more detail to the questions and share what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, you might use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$str = "AWS-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIngtc3MiOjEy/20160911/cn/user-service/request,SignedHeaders=host;x-aws-date, Signature=d9ee2d43f2067e4b8857f15fa8fff27820051d95a4ec31e93be866f201e0797a";
$res = array_map(function($x){
    return explode('=', $x)[1];
}, explode(',', $str));
print_r($res);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIngtc3MiOjEy/20160911/cn/user-service/request
    [1] => host;x-aws-date
    [2] => d9ee2d43f2067e4b8857f15fa8fff27820051d95a4ec31e93be866f201e0797a
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DGg37)

Answer (score 0):

That regularly/predictably formatted string is a "**AWS authorization header**" or a "**AWS Signature Version 4 header**".

You can use `sscanf()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1aaUr))

```
$str = "AWS-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIngtc3MiOjEy/20160911/cn/user-service/request,SignedHeaders=host;x-aws-date, Signature=d9ee2d43f2067e4b8857f15fa8fff27820051d95a4ec31e93be866f201e0797a";
var_export(
    sscanf(
        $str,
        'AWS-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=%[^,],SignedHeaders=%[^,], Signature=%[^,]'
    )
);
```

There is an alternative syntax whereby you provide the reference variables to populate with the matched values. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vv7UQ))

```
sscanf(
    $str,
    'AWS-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=%[^,],SignedHeaders=%[^,], Signature=%[^,]',
    $credentials,
    $headers,
    $signature
);

var_dump($credentials, $headers, $signature);
```

---

To create an associative array using the exact key and value pairs from the almost-ini-formatted text, use `parse_ini_string()` after tweaking the format into separate lines. This will be more forgiving of optional spaces around separators or differently ordered components. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kT4eQ))

```
var_export(
    parse_ini_string(
        preg_replace('/[, ]+/', "\n", $str)
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Credential' => 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIngtc3MiOjEy/20160911/cn/user-service/request',
  'SignedHeaders' => 'host',
  'Signature' => 'd9ee2d43f2067e4b8857f15fa8fff27820051d95a4ec31e93be866f201e0797a',
)
```

---

Using `preg_match_all()` is a little too cumbersome with named capture groups; and `preg_split()` will be a relative chore to ensure key-value relationships.